# Using a for loop and document.getElementById to populate an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

I have been trying to populate an array using a for loop and taking such values using `document.getElementById("spin " + i).value;`

The `ids` on my html for every input tag go from spin1 to spin18.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Or what I can change?

```
var nums = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= 18; i++){
    var num[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("spin" + i).value);

    nums.push(num[i]);

}

alert(nums.length);
```

Comment: What error you are getting? and please share your HTML as well.

Comment: `var num[i]` doesn't work. You can't create an array that way. Do `var num = parseInt(...); nums.push(num);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the problem?  You never mention what kind of results being generated or what the front-end html code looks like.

The js looks compilable, but here are some pointers.

### **The number 0 is before 1**

It's a good habit to get in this mind set, plus it might save you from making stupid mistakes later on.  Anyway, just to reinforce this, below is a number chart.

```
    0      10
    1      11
    2      12
    3      13
    4      14
    5      15
    6      16
    7      17
    8      18
    9      19
```

### **Avoid unnecessary variables**

Having a js compiler that optimizes redundant code is sadly new feature.  But still, why have two lines to maintain when you can have one.

```
var nums = [];

for( var i = 0; i < 18; i++ ) {
    nums[i] = parseInt( document.getElementById("spin" + i).value );
}
```

### **Don't push, insert**

The push method has an expensive overhead so use it with caution.

### **Loggers**

The console has a built in logger, why not use that instead of an alert box?

```
console.log( nums.length );
```

Comment: I agree with Dam. According to [this test](http://jsperf.com/push-vs-arr-ii), `.push` will significantly slower your code if you have a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var nums = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= 18; i++){
    var num= parseInt(document.getElementById("spin" + i).value);

    nums.push(num);

}

alert(nums.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to note:

1. As PSR has mentioned, you use:

```
var num[i]
```

when it should be

```
var num
```

1. `getElementById(id).value` only works for form elements, you have to use `.innerHTML` for divs.

This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sbqeT/

Comment: `getElementById(id).value only works for input elements` Not true, consider this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/JMnmz/).

Comment: @Derek: You are correct, would "form elements" be a more correct term?

Comment: "Form elements" sounds better.

Comment: Thanks for addressing the difference between innerHTML and value! It solved my problem!